# Querying CDC data takes a lot of time

Tags: sql-server, cdc

We have a table in mssql database, we have enabled CDC for that table.
No of records in the table are 7

However when we are querying the data using CDC function, the query keep in running state however the number of records in the capture instance is 0.

Sample Query

```
DECLARE @begin_time datetime, @end_time datetime, @from_lsn binary(10), @to_lsn binary(10);  
SET @begin_time = '2022-01-04 01:54:06';  
SET @end_time = '2022-01-07 13:23:06.457'; 
SET @from_lsn = sys.fn_cdc_map_time_to_lsn('smallest greater than or equal', @begin_time);  
SET @to_lsn = sys.fn_cdc_map_time_to_lsn('largest less than or equal', @end_time); 
SELECT * FROM cdc.fn_cdc_get_net_changes_dbo_MYTABLE (@from_lsn, @to_lsn, 'all');
```

Similar thing happening when we are trying to disable CDC for this table.

We are not sure, why this issue has been occurring.

We would appreciate if anyone can help me to understand the reason behind this issue.

Comment: Which version and build number of SQL Server? `select @@version` Have you checked if the cleanup job is running properly? See also https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/06/performance-tuning-sql-server-change-tracking/. Please share an *actual* (not *estimated*) execution plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan

Comment: The number of records in the table is not relevant - the mutation rate (that is, the amount of inserts/updates/deletes happening on the table) is what matters. Take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/cdc-capture-instance-ct-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15. How many rows are in that meta-table for the table that you've enabled CDC for? You can get a quick count by looking at sys.partitions for *that* table.